Is supremum of a continuous function continuous either?
In Strom's paper 'Note on cofibrations II' the proof of Lemma 4, for a cofibered pair of topological spaces $(X,A)$ (which means $A\subset X$ and the inclusion map $i\colon A\to X$ is a cofibration), he constructed a continuous function $\varphi\colon X\to I$ by
$$\varphi(x)=\sup_{t\in I}|t-\pi_2r(x,t)|,$$
where $r\colon X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I \to X\times I$ is a retraction, and $\pi_2\colon X\times I\to I$ is the projection onto the second coordinate.
My question is how to proof the continuity of the function $\varphi$?
In general, for a continuous function $f\colon X\times I\to I$, is the function $\varphi(x)=\sup_{t\in I}\{f(x,t)\}$ continuous either?

$I$ is the unit interval?

We shall prove the following
Lemma. Let $K$ be compact and $f : X \times K \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Then
$$F : X \to \mathbb R, F(x) = \sup_{k \in K} f(x,k) = \sup f(\{x\} \times K)$$
is continuous.
Note that $f(\{x\} \times K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ so that $\sup f(\{x\} \times K) \in f(\{x\} \times K)$.
Proof. Let $x_0 \in X$ and $t_0 = F(x_0)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $k_0 \in K$ with $f(x_0,k_0) > t_0 - \epsilon$. There are open neighborhoods $U$ of $x_0$ in $X$ and $O$ of $k_0$ in $K$ such that $f(U \times O) \subset(t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$. [Actually we do not need $O$, it suffices to know $f(U \times \{k_0\}) \subset(t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$.] For $x \in U$ we have $F(x) \ge f(x,k_0) > t_0 - \epsilon$. Moreover, $V = f^{-1}((-\infty,t_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}))$ is open in $X \times K$, where $\{x_0\} \times K \subset V$ (since $f(x_0,k) \le F(x_0) = t_0 < t_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$)). Hence there is an open neighborhood $W$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $W \times K \subset V$, i.e. we have $f(W \times K) \subset (-\infty,t_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2})$. For $x \in W$ we get $F(x) = \sup_{k \in K} f(x,k) \le t_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < t_0 + \epsilon$. Therefore $F(U \cap W) \subset (t_0 - \epsilon, t_0 + \epsilon)$.
Remark. In the above Lemma one can replace the codomain $\mathbb   R$ of $f$ by any subset $Y \subset \mathbb R$. This is a consequence of the following two facts:

A function $\phi : Z \to Y$ living on a topological space $Z$ is continuous if and only if $\phi' = i \circ \phi : Z \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, where $i : Y \to \mathbb R$ denotes inclusion.

$\sup f(\{x\} \times K) \in f(\{x\} \times K)$. Hence if the codomain of $f$ is $Y$, then $F(x) \in  f(\{x\} \times K) \subset Y$, i.e. we get a function $F : X \to Y$.


